# iptables: route packets to example.com via public proxy

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, proxy

I want to access certain websites via a public proxy and I can't seem to get it right using iptables. Let's say I want to access example.com having ip address 1.2.3.4 via a public proxy at 5.6.7.8:8080. What I do is:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 1.2.3.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --dst 5.6.7.8 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4:80
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst 1.2.3.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8:8080
```

But then I can't load the webpage at all (as if the proxy is not reachable, but it is, because I test it by setting it in the browser's proxy settings when no routing rules are set).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to enable IP forwarding using:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then add pre-routing rule using (I think you dont need to mention whole 1.2.3.0/24 network):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8:8080
```

Add post-routing rule using:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had indeed forgotten to enable ip forward, but even after doing so, it doesn't work:
Adding the two rules you suggested does not go through the proxy (I tried using wtfismyip.com as the example.com and I can see my real public IP).
Adding the OUTPUT rule I originally had, gets me back to where I was (I cannot connect at all)
Replacing the PREROUTING with OUTPUT, simply loads the default page of the proxy server.

I'm a bit confused as to which rule applies to which packet in my case... I want to stress that both target and proxy ip addresses here are external.

Comment: My first iptables rule translates the destination IP address of the packet from 1.2.3.4 to 5.6.7.8 and port from 80 to 8080. The second rules translates the source IP address of packet to the outbound interface of your linux machine.

Comment: Thanks, I see, this is what I thought as well. But just these two rules do not make any apparent change (I still see my real IP address), so something must be missing...

Comment: After reading http://blog.webernetz.net/2014/01/22/at-a-glance-http-proxy-packets-vs-normal-http-packets/ you can see that the packets must be forwarded to proxy server (i guess its working well in our case). Are you sure that proxy server is working as it should be?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the blog post clears some things up. I figured out why no change to the packets was happening: as explained here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280948/iptables-doesnt-redirect-http-traffic-to-my-squid-proxy , I need to use the OUTPUT chain, instead of PREROUTING, since iptables is running on my machine, the same machine as the web browser establishing connection to 1.2.3.4. With the OUTPUT rule I am being redirected to the proxy server (which works fine), but I am getting it's / page (login) rather than the requested site (to be continued in the following post)

Comment: From what I got from the blog post you linked to, the requested URI in the packet should be changed for this to work, but I don't know how to do this with iptables, I don't think it's even possible.